# Merge data of one variable in matlab with another variable in another mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, merge

I have 2 mat files , I would like to merge these files by adding all the records from file1 to the end of file 2, I would like to inform you that these files include the same varaible as:

mat file1 include (100) records :

file name
distance value

mat file2 include (800) records:

file name
distance value

I want to get the file2 with 1000 records
 is it possible in matlab or not?

Answer (score 3):

### Updated version

So apparently you've got this in your files:

```
myStruct = struct('Names', cell(n,1), 'Distances', []);
```

Where all arrays (cell and normal matrices) contain the different samples in the rows.

You'll be doing something like:

```
struct1=load('file1.mat');
struct2=load('file2.mat');

struct2.myStruct.Names=[struct2.myStruct.Names;struct1.myStruct.Names];
struct2.myStruct.Distances=[struct2.myStruct.Distances;struct1.myStruct.Distances];
save('file2.mat','-struct',struct2);
```

Comment: Hi jpjacobs
Thank you for replying Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> MergeNewSimLBPMSHPAllBrodatz89912 at 8
    struct2.(fields{k})=[struct2(fields{k}); struct1(fields{k})];
 
>>

Comment: sorry for this error, I would like to inform you that when I applied your codin I get the following error :ndex exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> MergeNewSimLBPMSHPAllBrodatz89912 at 8
    struct2.(fields{k})=[struct2(fields{k}); struct1(fields{k})];

Comment: Also I would like to inform you that I get the file name of the second file from the : fields=fieldnames(struct2) not the name of the fields, I forgot to tell you that my files including struct of array and this struct including the two fileds (file name distance value ), thanks

Comment: I make the following modify : load  file1.mat ;
struct1=Rec1;   % Rec1 Is the Name of Struct of arry for file 1
load  file2.mat ;
struct2=Rec2;   % Rec2 Is the Name of Struct of arry for file 2
fields=fieldnames(struct2); 
for k=1:length(fields)
    struct2.(fields{k})=[struct2(fields{k});struct1(fields{k})];
end
save('file2.mat','-struct',struct2); But I get the error: Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma
separated
list expansion on left hand side.  Missing [] are the most likely
cause.

Comment: You should just clearly describe which variables are in both files, and what types they contain, and how you expect them to be merged. That would improve your question a lot, and make it easier to answer. As you can see, posting code in comments isn't useful.

Comment: I have two mat file, each one including struct of array, this struct of array containe two types of variables, one of character (image name) and the second one is neumeric (Distan values). I want to merge these two files, Is it is ok now? please I need your help, thanks

Comment: I changed my answer. You should actually put the specs of your structs in your question, instead of a comment to my answer.

Comment: please,1) I write the really fields in the first command as :  myStruct = struct('DisNo', 'ClasNa','SimNo',cell(567,1),'ImNam','Pres','Recal', []); for n, what it is represent?  it is represent the number of the records(sample) in the file, ok which number I put? I put the number of sample for the file that I want to merge it with second file, It is ok? ....2) I get the error: Reference to non-existent field 'myStruct'. how can I correct this error?thanks

Comment: With all due respect, but you really need to start thinking yourself. The code I gave you will work, if you adjust it to the names you use. for example, the error you cite comes from the fact that there *is no variable called myStruct* in the file you're loading. That aside, you should think about how you represent your data: which types(matrix, cell, struct), which sizes, which keys you use in your struct. If you fail to provide these *in your question* no one will be able to provide you code that actually runs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5982/discussion-between-jpjacobs-and-zenab)